# How do I move animations?

Tags: animation, keyframes, scene

I just made an animation that looks like this:

[image]

It's just an unmoving shaft with an object falling through. I used a physics simulation for the object and then baked it. My problem is that the placement for this animation isn't right compared to another simulation also going on in the scene, so I need to move one of them (preferably this one). How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parent the related objects to an empty, move the empty.

To parent, <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select the child (the animated object), then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select the parent object (the created empty) making it the active object. Then press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you! Super easy solution, 10/10 would recommend to a friend.