# Move an animation once it's baked

Tags: animation, soft-body

I have a baked physics animated object which I'd like to move into a different position - this appears to be quite awkward (because the position of the object is of course baked)

Is there an easy way to achieve this? I could reposition everything first and repeat the simulation, but this is actually quite challenging based the calculated positions of objects and how they need to be exported.

Comment: You can either move the location in the Graph Editor (by moving up or down a F curve, like for example the X Location), or parent your object to an empty and move the empty

Comment: Once the animation is baked - parenting to an empty doesn't appear to work (it only moves the animation on frame 1, as the other frames are baked into position)

Comment: What kind of physics are you talking about? If I parent a cube with rigid body for example to an empty, it works fine, I can move the empty and the cube follows, its new world reference is now the cube

Comment: Soft body. That approach works for me too, but once the animation is baked it works no longer (because the baking appears to fix the position in the frames)

Comment: oh ok that's something else

Comment: I've found a solution with the Mesh Cache Modifier, I can explain it more precisely if you want, see here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118475/move-a-soft-body-cloth-after-baking

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Rich Sedman's answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118475/move-a-soft-body-cloth-after-baking).

For *Soft Body* for example you can use the *Mesh Cache* modifier:

- Bake your physics
- Enable the *Import-Export: NewTek MDD Format* addon
- Select your object and *File > Export > Lightwave Point Cache (.mdd)* in order to save the mdd file
- Duplicate your object, remove the physics of the copy, give it the *Mesh Cache* modifier (second modifier, under *Data Transfer*), select the mdd in *File Path*

Your second object copies the physics of the original, except you can transform it.